# YOLOv8 - Predictions on a Test Image of Different Size

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo, yolov8

I trained a custom YOLOv8 object detection model using images of size 512,512 but when I test the model on a larger image, let us say of size 2145,1195 it fails miserably. Can anyone help me what could be the reason ? It works fine when I test it on image size of 512,512 ?

Answer (score 0):

The neural network contains matrices of a certain size that work only with input images of a certain size. You need to resize the image before passing it to the network.

#### Pytorch

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("path/to/your/image.jpg")
desired_size = (224, 224)
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(desired_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])
resized_image = transform(image)
# Use Yolo here
```

#### Tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("path/to/your/image.jpg")
desired_size = (224, 224)
# Convert the PIL image to a TensorFlow tensor
image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
resized_image = tf.image.resize(image_tensor, size=desired_size)
# Use Yolo here
```